# Não é possível criar uma instância da classe android studio

Tags: android

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


private RecyclerView categoryRecyclerView;
private CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;

private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    categoryRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.category_recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    categoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    List<HomeViewModel> categoryModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    categoryModelList.add(new HomeViewModel("link", "Home"));
    categoryModelList.add(new HomeViewModel("link", "Electronics"));
    categoryModelList.add(new HomeViewModel("link", "Appliances"));
    categoryModelList.add(new HomeViewModel("link", "Furniture"));
    categoryModelList.add(new HomeViewModel("link", "Fashion"));
    categoryModelList.add(new HomeViewModel("link", "Toys"));
    categoryModelList.add(new HomeViewModel("link", "Sports"));
    categoryModelList.add(new HomeViewModel("link", "Wall Arts"));
    categoryModelList.add(new HomeViewModel("link", "Books"));
    categoryModelList.add(new HomeViewModel("link", "Shoes"));

    categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(categoryModelList);
    categoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
    categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    return view;
}
}
```

---

```java
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

private String CategoryIconLink;
private String categoryName;

public HomeViewModel(String categoryIconLink, String categoryName) {
    CategoryIconLink = categoryIconLink;
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}

public String getCategoryIconLink() {
    return CategoryIconLink;
}

public void setCategoryIconLink(String categoryIconLink) {
    CategoryIconLink = categoryIconLink;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}
}
```

---

```java
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<HomeViewModel> categoryModelList;

public CategoryAdapter(List<HomeViewModel> categoryModelList) {
    this.categoryModelList = categoryModelList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_item,viewGroup,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    String icon = categoryModelList.get(position).getCategoryIconLink();
    String name = categoryModelList.get(position).getCategoryName();
    viewHolder.setCategoryName(name);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categoryModelList.size();
}
```

---

```java
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView  categoryIcon;
    private TextView categoryName;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        categoryIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);
        categoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
    }

    private void setCategoryIcon(){

    }

    private void setCategoryName(String name){
        categoryName.setText(name);
    }
}
}
```

---

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


    frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_framelayout);
    setFragment(new HomeFragment());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.main_search_icon){
        return true;
    }else if (id == R.id.main_notification_icon){
        return true;
    }else if (id == R.id.main_cart_icon){
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_my_mall) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_orders) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_rewards) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_cart) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_wishlist) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_account) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_sign_out) {

    }

    return true;
}

private void setFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(frameLayout.getId(),fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

}
```

Log de Erros

```java
2019-09-11 13:38:13.575 25264-25264/com.example.grillo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.grillo, PID: 25264
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.grillo/com.example.grillo.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.grillo.ui.home.HomeViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.grillo.ui.home.HomeViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:184)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:241)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130)
        at com.example.grillo.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:28)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2595)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2097)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1871)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1827)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2660)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2610)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2619)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:904)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2656)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2610)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1335)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.grillo.ui.home.HomeViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:182)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:241) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130) 
        at com.example.grillo.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:28) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2595) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2097) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1871) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1827) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2660) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2610) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2619) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:904) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2656) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2610) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1335) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Comment: @Joanatha, Olá! Seria interessante que você colocasse o log de erros e que fizesse um comentário próximo a linha que está dando erro. A primeira coisa que fazemos quando pegamos m código defeituoso é analisar o log de erros e comparar com o código fonte.

Answer (score 1):

Essa informação:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<com.example.grillo.ui.home.HomeViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
> ```

Somada a essa informação:

> ```
>     at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:182)
>     at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:241)
>
>     at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164) 
>     at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130)
> ```

Indicam que o erro foi causado devido a ausência de um constructor sem argumentos para classe `HomeViewModel`.

Ao inicializar subclasses de `ViewModel` usando `ViewModelProviders`, por padrão, espera-se que sua classe tenha um construtor ausente de argumentos. Sua classe `HomeViewModel` possui apenas um constructor com dois argumentos.

```
public HomeViewModel(String categoryIconLink, String categoryName)
```

A solução direta é criar o constructor sem argumentos para `HomeViewModel` e para cada instancia criada a preencher suas propriedades.

Você também pode manter o constructor com dois argumentos mas para isso você terá que criar um class factory que implemente a interface [`ViewModelProvider.Factory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.Factory) para instanciar `HomeViewModel`, é uma solução trabalhosa mas que pode ser amenizada usando a biblioteca [ViewModelFactory](https://github.com/radutopor/ViewModelFactory).